# Generate multiple setups (e.g. InstallShield LE) from different compiling version of the same winforms program

Tags: windows, forms, installshield

I have my Windows Form program with multiple solution configurations.
Each configuration is different from only a variable.
For example:

Suppose that I have three different solution configurations:

1. AA
2. AB
3. AC

And in my code I have

```
#if AA
    public const string version = "AA";
#elif AB
    public const string version = "AB";
#elif AC
    public const string version = "AC";
#endif
```

Is there a way to generate multiple setups for each program? Program AA, program AB and program AC with their setup using only one command? (I have more than 20 configurations at the moment)

At the moment I have to compile them and generating the setup one by one using InstallShield LE.

Answer (score 0):

Give some more information please.

What is the result of your compile? One exe, multiple files,...??
What is the difference between the multiple setups? Only the linked in files or something more?

Comment: I need to have an installshield installer for each compiling settings. It has to be the same program but only with the constant variable in the question as difference.

Comment: Why don't you create one installer, where you link in all the different compiled programs.
You created for each compiled program a Release and define for each Release a unique Release Flag. 

On each feature, one feature per compiled program, you define the Release Flag it corresponds with. In this way you can build several setups from only one setup project.